# Series convergence test $∑_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\cos n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that the following series:

$∑_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\cos n^2}$ diverges (or converges).

What I have so far is this:

- the denominator will never be zero as there is no natural number that will yield $\frac{\pi}{2}+k2\pi$ as a result;
- the underlying sequence diverges, which (I think) I proved using the limit divergence test.

What I am not sure about is the fact that I substituted $n^2$ by $m$ stating that it had no impact on the sequence as when $n\rightarrow \infty$ so will $m$.

So I go on to show that $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\cos m}$ diverges and use that as a basis to conclude that my original sequence is divergent.

Is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about the question? Wouldn't the summation rather be: $∑_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{cos(n^2)} $?

Comment: You seem to want to invoke a fact of this shape: if $\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m)$ converges (or diverges), then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n^2)$ converges (or diverges). This is not a true fact. I recommend taking your strategy for proving that $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac1{\cos m}$ diverges and trying to apply that strategy directly to the more complicated series.

Comment: For a series to be convergent, its main term has to converge to zero. $\frac{1}{\cos(n^2)}$ cannot converge to zero since its absolute value is always $\geq 1$.

Comment: Way more subtle is to prove that something like $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(n^2)}{n}$$ *is* convergent.

Comment: @GregMartin Not entirely, in my explanation I use as an argument that in both cases the cos is bounded by -1 and 1. My argument is that, because of that, both sequences are similar with the exception of the increase in frequency. - (edit: not sure about that argument anymore...)

Comment: You don't have to show that $\frac{1}{\cos(n^2)}$ diverges (which is true but not easy to establish). Rather, as other users pointed out, all you have to show is that $\frac{1}{\cos(n^2)}$ *does not converge to $0$*. This is much easier to show, since you have $\left|\frac{1}{\cos(n^2)}\right| \geq 1$.